# Screen and Text blurry in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

There is some issue with the display sometimes in ubuntu. This occurs if I leave it aside for few minutes and unlock the screen. Please check the screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPr4.jpg

Comment: which nvidia driver are you using ?